# keep std vector/list sorted while insert, or sort all

Tags: c++, sorting, std, stdvector

Lets say I have 30000 objects in my vector/list. Which I add one by one.
I need them sorted.
Is it faster to sort all at once (like std::sort), or keep vector/list sorted while I add object one by one?

vector/list WILL NOT be modified later.

Comment: Neither. Use `std::set`. Edit: unless you want to put all objects in, then sort them, and then never modify the container again. In that case, just use a vector and sort it once.

Comment: @Nick: yes, `set` is _always_ sorted.  Maybe you're thinking of `unordered_set`?

Comment: `std::vector` and `std::sort` probably will be several times faster than `std::set`. Both are `O(N log N)` but the vector uses less memory and is contiguous in memory.

Comment: @MSalters: `std::set::insert` is O(log N), not O(N Log N). If you have to have it sorted after every single insert, `std::set` is much more efficient.

Comment: @VoidStar: That's for a single element; N inserts is trivially O(N log N). Of course, keeping a vector sorted on every insert is worse (naively O(N*N*logN) but you optimally O(N*N) as you need to move O(N) elements on an insert in the middle)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are keeping your vector list sorted while inserting elements one by one , you are basically performing an insertion sort, that theoretically runs O(n^2) in worst case. The average case is also quadratic, which makes insertion sort impractical for sorting large arrays.

With your input of ~30000 , it will be better to take all inputs and then sort it with a faster sorting algorithm.

**EDIT:** 
As @Veritas pointed out, We can use faster algorithm to search the position for the element (like binary search). So the whole process will take O(nlg(n)) time. 
Though , It may also be pointed that here inserting the elements is also a factor to be taken into account. The worst case for inserting elements takes O(n^2)  that is still the overall running time if we want to keep the array sorted.

Sorting after input is still by far the better method rather than keeping it sorted after each iteration.

Comment: The whole procedure of keeping the array sorted while inserting is the insertion sort. So his way of input is insertion sort in itself. When The container is already sorted, well, that is a very specific case.

Comment: @Veritas You're forgetting that on a vector, [arbitrary] insert takes O(n) time. O(n) time per element with n total elements makes it n^2. Finding where to insert the element has nothing to do with the quadratic nature of it. See http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-summary.html#vector

Comment: @wrhall I deleted my previous comments because I didn't read the question correctly. I thought he was occasionally inserting elements, resulting in a O(n) time insertion.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping the `vector` sorted during insertion would result in quadratic performance since on average you'll have to shift down approximately half the vector for each item inserted. Sorting once at the end would be `n log(n)`, rather faster.

Depending on your needs it's also possible that `set` or `map` may be more appropriate.